# Difference between a RemoteAuthenticationHandler<TOptions> and AuthenticationHandler<TOptions>?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, authentication, authorization, asp.net-core-authenticationhandler

Currently the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/?view=aspnetcore-5.0) does not mention what a `RemoteAuthenticationHandler<TOptions>` really does, other than the fact it

> performs authentication using a separately hosted provider.

What provider?

Comment: that means the provider is not in the same host with your application. It's not even in the same process with the request processing pipeline. That means there will be some data transferred back & forth between the separately hosted provider & the web application. The protocol & steps to perform authentication are usually different from the hosted providers. I think you can look into the source code to understand more (not required for normal using but if you want to understand more, just read it).